# python - find occurrences of strings from a reference file within an input file

Tags: python

I have two files. Call one file as a reference file. This file contains a list of strings each on a separate line. The other file is an input file. It also has strings on on each line. 
I want to find the occurrence of each string from the reference file within the input file. This is my code

```
def count_line_occurrences(ref_list,input_list):
  line_counter = {}
  # Initialization
  for ref_line in ref_list:
    ref_line = ref_line.rstrip()
    line_counter[ref_line] = 0
  for input_line in input_list:
      input_line = input_line.rstrip()

  for ref_line in ref_list:
    #print ref_line
    for input_line in input_list:
      #print input_line
      if str(input_line).find(str(ref_line)) != -1:
        print 'found ' + ref_line
        line_counter[ref_line] += 1
  return line_counter
```

However it is not working. 
Note - This is not a HW problem. But this is a part of a bigger task. Also, strangely, I have implemented this part in Perl and it is working fine. I want to shift the project to Python and I am having issues here. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you define "not working?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sort of works for me. Calling your function like ...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = count_line_occurrences(["a","b","c"],["c","c","b","a"])
    print x
```

prints out ...

```
found a
found b
found c
found c
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

@Sumod ... isn't that the expected behavior ?

**Edition after seeing @Sumod's input data**

So the problem with your input is that you are not cleaning correctly the trailing characters `\t\n`.

The following code works ...

```
def count_line_occurrences(ref_list,input_list):
  line_counter = {}

  ref_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(" \t\n"),ref_list)
  input_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(" \t\n"),input_list)

  # Initialization
  for ref_line in ref_list:
    line_counter[ref_line] = 0

  for ref_line in ref_list:
    #print ref_line
    for input_line in input_list:
      #print input_line
      if str(input_line).find(str(ref_line)) != -1:
        print 'found ' + ref_line
        line_counter[ref_line] += 1
  return line_counter
```

notice that prior to the init of your counters I do the cleaning of both input lists with ...

```
ref_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(" \t\n"),ref_list)
input_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(" \t\n"),input_list)
```

The `string.strip` function in python receives the characters I want to clean up.

For the input ...

```
    ref_list = ['.Net Framework\n', '7-Zip\n', 'ACT DCP \n', 'ActivePerl \n', 'ActiveState Komodo Edit\n', 'ActiveTCL \n', 'Adobe Flash Player\n']
    input_list = ['7-Zip 4.57\t\n', 'WebEx\t\n', 'Adobe Acrobat Reader 8.0.0\t\n', 'Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX\t10.0.32.18\n']
    x = count_line_occurrences(ref_list,input_list)
    print x
```

I get ...

```
{'ActiveState Komodo Edit': 0, '.Net Framework': 0, 'ACT DCP': 0, 'ActivePerl': 0, 'Adobe Flash Player': 1, '7-Zip': 1, 'ActiveTCL': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problems is that my reference list appears as - ['.Net Framework\n', '7-Zip\n', 'ACT DCP \n', 'ActivePerl \n', 'ActiveState Komodo Edit\n', 'ActiveTCL \n', 'Adobe Flash Player\n' ... and so on] and my input list appears as - ['7-Zip 4.57\t\n', 'WebEx\t\n', 'Adobe Acrobat Reader 8.0.0\t\n', 'Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX\t10.0.32.18\n', .... and so on'. So e.g. 7-Zip\n cannot be found in the input list. This is my issue.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, SO was down for me. In the meantime, I tried this approach and it worked for me.

ref_list = [string.strip(ref_item) for ref_item in ref_list]
input_list = [string.strip(input_item) for input_item in input_list]

I am going to accept your answer as it seems a good alternate approach.